# Leaflet Auto Resetting Layers When Zooming

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, arcgis, reset

I am currently creating a map with leaflet and I have run into a peculiar situation where my map layers reset after running a query function, zooming in, and then zooming out:

[image: Original View]

After zooming in with the query in place and then zooming out it resets itself:

[image: After Zooming out]

It almost appears as if the map is resetting itself after the user zooms out past the initial scale of 6. It essentially resets the query and I'm not sure where the issue is in the code. In a perfect world the queried layer stays queried until the user either refreshes the page or changes the query themselves.

Full JS, CSS, and HTML:

```js
//Main Map Baselayer
  var street = L.layerGroup();
  L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(street);

//Establish baselayers
  var baseLayers = {
    Streetmap: street,
    Geographic: L.esri.basemapLayer('NationalGeographic'),
    Gray: L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray')
  };

//Call Food Insecurity Polygon from ArcGIS Online, Popup, and Query

  var foodInsecurity = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/HRPe58bUyBqyyiCt/arcgis/rest/services/Yemen_Final_WFL1/FeatureServer/4',
    style: function (feature) {
        if (feature.properties.ML2 === 2) {
            return {color:'yellow', weight: 2};
        } else if (feature.properties.ML2 === 3) {
            return {color: 'orange', weight: 2};
        } else if (feature.properties.ML2 === 4) {
            return {color: 'red', weight: 2};
        } else {
            return {color: 'grey', weight: 2}
        } 
        }
  });

//Create and set basic controls of map
  var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl: true,
    center: [15.8527, 47.5164],
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 15,
    layers: [street, foodInsecurity]
  });


//Create main overlay features 
  var overlays = {
    'Food Insecurity':foodInsecurity,

  };

    //Bind a popup for the food insecurity
    foodInsecurity.bindPopup(function (layer) {
    return L.Util.template('<p>The level of food insecurity in this region is <strong>{ML2} out of 5</strong>.</p>', layer.feature.properties);
  });

    //Query by specific values for food insecurity (indeex.html page)
    var insecurityFood = document.getElementById('insecurity');

      insecurityFood.addEventListener('change', function () {
        foodInsecurity.setWhere(insecurityFood.value);
      });

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow: hidden;}

#map {
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}

  #query3 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 85.5vh;
    right: -6vh;
    right: -2.8vw;
    z-index: 400;
    background: white;
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    padding-left: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-size: 1vw;
    width: 14vw;
    height: 4vh;
  }

  #query3 select {
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-size: 1vw;
    width: 11vh;
    width: 6vw;
    height: 3vh;
    height: 1.7vw;
  }

#query3 select:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!---Leaflet CSS--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    
    <!---Leaflet JS--->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <!----ESRI JS---->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.4.1/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-xY2smLIHKirD03vHKDJ2u4pqeHA7OQZZ27EjtqmuhDguxiUvdsOuXMwkg16PQrm9cgTmXtoxA6kwr8KBy3cdcw=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    
    <!-- Load Personal Stylesheet -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>   
<body>
<!--- Create Map -->
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Create Query for Food Insecurity -->
<div class="leaflet-bar1">
    <div id="query3" class="leaflet-barq3">
      <label>
        Food Insecurity:
        <select id="insecurity">
          <!-- make sure to encase string values in single quotes for valid sql -->
            <option value="1=1">All</option>
            <option value="ML2='2'">Stressed</option>
            <option value="ML2='3'">Emergency</option>
            <option value="ML2='4'">Crisis</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
<!--    my js script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I copied your code and it is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/crthbdx5/ have somewhere else code?

Comment: It still happens when I look at your example. Select a query and then try zooming in real far and then zooming out. It resets the layer exactly the way it was before.

Comment: I didn't saw the querys because of the css. I found out that this is always happen when you zoom back to the init zoom. When you change the init zoom you can test it: `L.map('map', { ... zoom: 8,.... }`

Comment: Any ideas on how to make sure that it stops resetting itself once it goes back to the initial zoom? Or any ideas on how to make it impossible for the user to skip the initial zoom?